# Woocommerce category display: Show subcategories & products excluding subcategory products hiding parent subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi all I am using this function used in another stack over flow post from like 2018 which shows my categories children categories and products that are assigned to that level instead of showing the children categories and also all the products in the children:

```
    function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
    if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
     array (
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
         'include_children' => false
         )
        )
       );
     }
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

this works completely fine for specific categories but when I go up a level it hides all the subcategories in there for example:

[shows parent categories fine](https://www.aurora-rock.co.uk/shop)

[Pall subcategories are hidden](https://www.aurora-rock.co.uk/product-category/tableware/bevande/)

[works perfectly](https://www.aurora-rock.co.uk/product-category/tableware/bevande/maize/)

Hopefully someone knows a fix for this.